# .Find() is not working in excel file opened through another excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an excel file where i need to take data from another excel file which i am taking as input using VBA macro. Now if i copy the whole data from input file and paste it in main file then that works. But i want only selected data from the input file so i am using .Find() to get the required data but .Find() is not working in this input file though the same thing works in any excel file.

Here is the sample code i am using :

-----This code works------

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim responseworkbook As Workbook
    Dim macroworkbook As Workbook

    Set macroworkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a file to capture input data")

    If strFileToOpen = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a valid input file!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen
        Set responseworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        strOpenFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    With ActiveSheet
                lastColumn_res = .Cells(1,         Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                lastrow_res = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
        For j = 1 To 1
            responseworkbook.Activate
            If Cells(1, j).Value = "ABC" Then 'ABC is column name
                Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(lastrow_res, j + 1)).Copy
                macroworkbook.Activate
                Sheets("selected data").Select
                With ActiveSheet
                    firstrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End With
                Range("D" & firstrow).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
       End If
    End If
```

-----------------This code does not work--------------------
In above code if i replace

```
    Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(lastrow_res, j + 1)).Copy
```

with

```
    rng = responseworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:C").Find("12/31/2001")
    or
    rng = Sheets(1).Range("A:C").Find("12/31/2001", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    or
    rng = .Find("12/31/2001", , xlValues, xlWhole)
```

Here rng is a Range variable and it is not working because rng is coming as nothing.

Could you please check where i am doing it wrong because if i use the same line of code to find the data it works.

Many Thanks

Comment: to be sure to be in the right workbook, `Set responseworkbook = Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen`. don't use activate select, ...

Comment: don't even think about using `Pastspecial` for only values : `RangeB.value = RangeA.Value` , shorter, faster, more efficient.

Comment: `For j=1 to 1` .... good one.

Comment: I don't see the variable declaration of  `strFileToOpen ` . Anyway , if user cancels or aborts or enters nothing , answer is `False`, not `""` , wich should be `VbNullstring` , refer here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Does your code even compile ? I see  no `Next J` . Variables should always be capitalized, easier to debug...

Comment: if `Rng`is a Range, then `rng =...` will error. Instead `Set Rng = ...`

Comment: And stop explaining things with "not working".
What error message do you get, what result do you expect , and what result do you get... ?

Comment: @Patrick - Thanks. I just pasted a part of my code. will surely take care of the things you mentioned while posting a question next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Preferably you should create a reference to the workbook you want to search, and then to the worksheet you want to search. Here's a minimal example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindInOtherWorkbook()

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\foo.xlsx")
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'you can change Range("A1:F20") to whatever area you need to search in
    Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range("A1:F20").Find(What:="foo")
    'use line below to search all cells of wsTarget worksheet
    'Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Cells.Find(What:="foo")

    If rngTarget Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Cannot find foo"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Found cell at: " & rngTarget.Address
        Debug.Print "Found cell in sheet: " & rngTarget.Worksheet.Name
        Debug.Print "Found cell in book: " & rngTarget.Parent.Parent.Name
    End If

    wbTarget.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Robin. 
Can't we define the range in which we will find the value. the reason is i have different type of data in different columns and i am looking for data correspond to a date. Say type A data has some "a" value and type B has some "b" value for a specific date.

Comment: Yes, instead of using `Cells` you can use `Columns("A:A")` or some other expression that returns a `Range` - see my updated code sample.